Cassandra failing to start on new node
I am trying to add a new node to an existing cluster. When I start cassandra on the new node I am seeing the below error.
**ERROR [main] 2024-11-27 17:04:13,039 CassandraDaemon.java:759 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No sources found for (6583315391450457888,6586615426701824871]**

Has anyone had this before or have any suggestions on what this could mean?
Thanks

Most likely you have a keyspace that is replicating to a data center that doesnt exist. When it starts bootstrapping its looking to stream data from it but it cant find any nodes. Type describe schema in cqlsh on a different node and look for the CREATE KEYSPACE lines and go over them. It is case sensitive so look carefully.

I have check this and they all have the expected vdcs. I have recently decommissioned a node and altered some keyspaces as port of that to remove the keyspaces from the vdc I decommissioned. Have i maybe missed something?
